# How to spec this capacitor

Tags: capacitor

Im working from a reference design for an NXP home automation modem.

[image]

The capacitor with the green arrow is well described.

The capacitor with the red arrow is not. The schematic seems to suggest that the capacitor is polarized. I didn't think that a polarized could be used in such an application. (an offline dropping power supply)

What type of capacitor (aluminum, film, ceramic, etc...) would be suggested in this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2µF capacitor with a working voltage of at least 250V, any kind. ESR and ESL don't really matter here, since there is already a (relatively) decently large resistor and inductor in series with it. It doesn't need to be polarized since polarization is never an advantage, and ceramic capacitors are already available in larger capacities (although not necessarily at that voltage).

Comment: Is it safe to use a polarized capacitor there?

Comment: @DoxyLover I updated the picture for clarity. My concern comes from the negative going voltage. When the positive going voltage happens, D1 is reverse biased, D2 is forward biased and D3 clips the voltage off at 7v5. When the negative voltage happens D1 is forward biased and the capacitor would be exposed to the line voltage, would it not?

Comment: My bad. I somehow thought both diodes were in the same direction. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The working voltage of this capacitor must be at least :
250 * sqrt(2) -> 353 V min --- 400V or 600V is better.